# From client this works perfectly with SELECT and returns boolean. But, as Function it does not work as plpgsl

Tags: plpgsql

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.verify_grp_pw()
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    verify boolean;

BEGIN
    verify = (substring(( SELECT bristo_contacts_groups_pwd from bristo_contacts_groups
                 WHERE bristo_contacts_groups_group = ( SELECT 
                       bristo_contacts_session_grpname FROM
                       bristo_contacts_session WHERE
                       bristo_contacts_session_username = current_user)),1,64) = 
    encode(digest(substring(( SELECT bristo_contacts_groups_pwd from bristo_contacts_groups
                 WHERE bristo_contacts_groups_group = ( SELECT 
                       bristo_contacts_session_grpname FROM
                       bristo_contacts_session WHERE
                       bristo_contacts_session_username = current_user)),66,97) || 
                       ( SELECT 
                       bristo_contacts_session_grppwd FROM
                       bristo_contacts_session WHERE
                       bristo_contacts_session_username = current_user), 'sha256'),'hex'));
    RETURN verify;
END;
$function$
```

Comment: What is the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The question is ultimately how do I get the boolean value to return properly.  If I run the query it works fine from client.  Run as policy it fails.